# Завернуть ссылки c изображениями на свой файл

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Работает:

```
$str = "http://element-bmw.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/323e33885d8518e1eddecde0a54a18b7-702x336.jpg <br> http://element-bmw.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/auto_parts_volkswagen_golf_3-768x450.jpg";
$str2 = preg_replace('/http:\/\/(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)/i','//site.ru/misc/img.php?url=http://$1.$2',$str);
echo '<pre>'.print_r([$str,$str2],TRUE).'</pre>';
```

Не работает:

```
$str = "http://rambler.ru <br> http://element-bmw.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/323e33885d8518e1eddecde0a54a18b7-702x336.jpg <br> http://element-bmw.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/auto_parts_volkswagen_golf_3-768x450.jpg";
$str2 = preg_replace('/http:\/\/(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)/i','//site.ru/misc/img.php?url=http://$1.$2',$str);
echo '<pre>'.print_r([$str,$str2],TRUE).'</pre>';
```

С регулярками на вы, рассчитываю на вашу помощь.

Comment: в чем там вообще разница то? нам глаза ломать и пытаться ее найти самим?

Comment: ок. разница в том, что в регулярку попадает вся строка от начала первого `http` до первого вхождения расширения картинки. в первом случае это просто первая ссылка (ибо она на картинку). Во втором случае это две ссылки подряд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, выражение `/http:\/\/(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)/i` будет соответствовать строке начиная от первого вхождения `http` и до первого попавшегося `(jpg|jpeg|....)`. Вызвано это тем, что используется маска `(.*?)`, что соответствует любому символу.

В вашем же случае (в приведенном), поскольку ссылки, видимо разделены пробелами, то надо их исключить, из всех символов, то есть использовать, например `(\S*?)` либо, если в разделителе будет тэг, то можно угловую скобку тоже исключить `([^\s<]*?)`

Comment: Не могу сообразить как использовать. `/http:\/\/([^\s<]?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)/i` не работает

Comment: @borodatych звездочка то никуда не делась там. я правда ее забыл написать.